# Built-ins for discrete ArgMax or ArgMin?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Wondering whether there are discrete versions of `ArgMax` / `ArgMin`, that is, something that will find the part of an expression at which some function `f` of the elements is maximized (or minimized).

`Last[Ordering[f/@list]]` and `First[Ordering[f/@list]]` will do, but the following does not work:

```
ArgMax[Function[i, (f/@list)[[i]]], i]
```

Comment: If you use Ordering, `Ordering[list, 1]` is more efficient than `First@Ordering[list]`

Comment: What if the function is bivariate, e.g., f(x,y), and we want to find argmax or argmin over both x and y?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess `Max` and `Min` are the best fit for discrete lists.

```
f[x_] := x Sin[x];
list = RandomReal[10, 10^6];
(Position[#, Max[#], 2][[1, 1]]) &@(f /@ list)
```

One can forcefully use `NArgMax` or `NArgMin` for this purpose but they are likely to be extremely inefficient! One such example

```
list = RandomReal[10, 1000];
ob[i_?IntegerQ] := (f /@ list)[[i]];
ob@NArgMax[{Evaluate@ob[x],1<= x<= Length@list&&Element[x,Integers]},x]//AbsoluteTiming
```

> {5.8344103, 7.91672}

Where as

```
Max[f /@ list]// AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0., 7.91672}

For timing comparison with solution using `Ordering` see the following plot. Horizontal axes shows the data length of `list` and the vertical axes is denoting computation time in seconds. I have tested it in an Intel i7 PC with 64 GB RAM.

[image]

As one can see if you compile the functions you get even better speed ups.

```
cf=Compile[{{x,_Real,1}},
      Module[{listval,max},
             listval=# Sin[#]&/@x;
             max=Max[listval];
             (Position[listval,max])[[1,1]]
             ],
      CompilationTarget->"C",
      RuntimeAttributes->{Listable},Parallelization->True];
```

Comment: This seems to be much faster than the other proposal on large inputs.

Comment: Yes I will update the answer with timing comparison.

Comment: `Ordering[f /@ list, -1]` for argmax and `Ordering[f /@ list,1]` for argmin seems to be faster than both `Position-Max` combination and `Ordering[list,f[#1] < f[#2] &]`.

Answer (score 4):

`Ordering` is good for this if you use a custom ordering function:

```
f=Sin;
list = RandomReal[{0, Pi}, 100];
First@Ordering[list, 1, f[#1] < f[#2] &]
```

And similarly for maximum replacing 1 with -1 (or < with >)

Comment: Manually supplying an ordering function seems to be much slower than just using `Ordering[f/@list,1]` as kguler recommended in a comment to an answer above.

Answer (score 3):

Version 10 has a new function `FindPeaks` that can be used here:

```
f[x_] := x Sin[x];
list = Range[1, 10, 0.1];
FindPeaks[f /@ list]
```

This returns the location (in the list) and value of the local maxes. Another new function that's related is `MaxDetect`, which returns a vector of zeros (at all the non-max locations) and ones (at all the max locations).

```
MaxDetect[f /@ list]
```

`MaxDetect` also works nicely on 2D and 3D data arrays and images, and there is also `MinDetect` that does what you would expect.